# Laravel 5.8 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `contacts` order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0' at line 1 (SQL: select from `contacts` order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0)

[image]

Comment: You don't actually select any columns, as you can see your query is `select from contacts order by created_at desc limit 10 offset 0`. You need to add the columns you are selecting between `select` and `from`.

Comment: use DB::enableQuerylog and DB::getQuerylog for debug

Comment: Hi, include some code so that we know what is the issue.

Comment: How are you executing your request ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message I guess you need to update your query

```
select * from contacts order by created_at desc limit 10 offset 0
```